# WiX bundle with replacement MSIs deleting payload after install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

### Summary

I have a bundle that is deleting the files on an upgrade.  It is deleting them because the old MSI uninstall is firing after the new MSI install has completed.

Since they have the same files with different component ids reference counting isn't able to prevent it.

I need to ensure the files are present at the end of the install process.

### History

#### Bundles mk 1

Two bundles with several MSIs were created.  They share some MSIs but also have their own unique content.

- Upgrade from mk1 to mk1 works just fine for both bundles

#### Bundles mk 2

One of the bundles has been changed to have some replacement MSIs.  It no longer has any shared MSIs.  The new MSIs have the same payload as they did before and the same feature ids but have different upgrade codes and component ids.

- Upgrade from mk1 -> mk2 only works for the unchanged bundle.
- Upgrade from mk2 -> mk2 is just fine for both bundles.
- Upgrade from mk1 -> mk2 results in the payload being missing for the changed bundle.
- A repair will restore the files.
- The log files show that the mk1 cached MSI uninstall fired after the mk2 MSI was already installed and this is what removed all the files.

### Problem

The missing files are obviously a problem for getting from mk1 to mk2.  It's impractical to ask customer's to do a repair if they upgrade from mk1 to mk2.

I initially tried forcing the features to local until I found the uninstall log files and found the MSIs were already installing ok - just the cleanup was in an unexpected place.

I was hoping I could just change the order of the bundle's sequence but it doesn't appear to have any install execute sequence of its own to tweak.

I can detect when the bundle is going from mk1 to mk2 and attempt to change things but I don't know what to change.

Perhaps I need to detect the cached bundle and exec a command line uninstall against it?

I'd prefer not to put custom actions into the MSIs but I will if that's how to fix it.  I'm hoping it can be fixed from within the bundle.

### Options Considered

1. Have the bundle execute a command line uninstall of the previous bundle explicitly if it's a mk1 to mk2 upgrade.
2. Assign new feature ids to the new MSIs and include the RTM of the mk1 MSIs anyway, force the mk1 MSI feature states to Absent and ensure the mk2 MSIs run after the mk1 MSIs.
3. Force a repair at the end of the bundle install by invoking itself with the repair option.

### Implementing

Adding in what I've worked out will sort of work.  It comes with its own new set of problems to solve.

I get the info on the cached bundle in DetectRelatedBundle.  From there I can look up the registry under one of these locations :

```
HLKM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<ProductCode>
HLKM:Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<ProductCode>
```

That gives me the location of the cached bundle in the `InstallSource` registry entry.

During the PlanComplete I then shell out to the cached bundle's silent modify functionality to tell it to remove the shared features so they're removed before the new bundle puts the new files in place.

The new problems are:

- The features don't migrate well.  It installs only the previously selected features but the modify and uninstall believe all features to be present.
- There's no rollback if it goes wrong.
- I don't know what happens if I run unelevated from a command line silent upgrade yet.  Potential problem here.

Comment: Take the bundle out of the equation. Can these packages upgrade the old ones?

Comment: No.  The mk2 MSIs are intentionally different to allow a side-by-side installation.  They contain the same files for now but as time progresses the content will diverge.

Comment: Actually, let me elaborate a bit on that.  Some of the MSIs are different.  In mk1 there are five MSIs.  Three shared between bundles A and B and one unique each.  So bundle A has MSIs 1,2,3,4 and bundle B has MSIs 2,3,4,5.  When we go to mk2 there are no shared MSIs - bundle A has MSIs 1,2,3,4 and bundle B has MSIs 2b,3b,4b,5.

Comment: If there's overlap, they're not side-by-side. You're trying to use a bundle to fix your packages; that's not going to work.

Comment: I'm constrained by the decisions of the business.  They have decided that the product needs to fork but that existing customers need a seamless upgrade experience.  I'm open for any suggestions on how this can be achieved.  The obvious requirements are that the MSIs need to double up for 2,3,4 to 2,3,4 and 2a,3a,4a.  I'm just stuck with the technical implementation on getting the mk1 transition to mk2 seamless.